# Abort createAsyncThunk before condition promise resolve

Tags: redux-toolkit

I abort thunk before the condition is resolved. But after resolving the condition, the thunk is still executed.

```
export const sampleThunk = createAsyncThunk('sampleThunk', async () => {
  console.log('do something async');
}, {
  condition: () => new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(true), 1000);
  }),
});
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const sampleThunkAction = dispatch(sampleThunk());

    sampleThunkAction.abort();
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Expect: sampleThunk does nothing after abortion

Answer (score 0):

Abort is used to abort an already executing async thunk (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#canceling-while-running), but in your example, you are calling the sampleThunkAction.abort() before it's even started because of your setTimeout of 1 second.

Your example:

- dispatch thunk
- condition timeout started
- call abort() (=> does nothing)
- condition tiemout ended (1s)
- execute thunk started
- execute thunk ended

You can:

- dispatch thunk
- condition timeout started
- condition timeout ended
- execute thunk started
- call abort()
- thunk will be stopped

Then in this case your expected behaviour will happen.

If you want a condition to prevent your thunk of being executed, that's definitely what the condition param is for.